# String.format() not working with EditText in Android

Tags: android, string

I am using the following code

```
Tx1XKBytes = (Tx1XBytes.doubleValue()/1024.0);            //Tx1XKBytes is long variable
BytesSent1X.setText(String.format("%.2f", Tx1XKBytes) +" KB");   //BytesSent1X is EdiText
```

I want the variable *Tx1XKBytes* to have precision upto two decimal point like *23.46* but it is not working. The result shows the whole value like *23.467658*.

Comment: Long variables do not have a decimal component - does that mean Tx1XKBytes is actually a `double`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this format...

```
String.format("%1$,.2f", doubleValue);
```

as follows....

```
BytesSent1X.setText(String.format("%1$,.2f", Tx1XKBytes) +" KB");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DecimalFormat class From Java like : -

```
DecimalFormat mDecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(".00");
```

It has format Method to format decimal digits.

Comment: I tried this but it is also not working with EditText.